# Build Qt Project in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: qt, jenkins, svn, jenkins-pipeline

Trying to build a Qt project from SVN in Jenkins using Pipeline script, but not entirely sure how to do it. I keep getting a system file cannot be found failure on Jenkins.

I've setup a new item that is Pipeline, and I've set it to use Subversion for scm and given it the correct path.

I've told it where the jenkinsfile is. The jenkinsfile just contains the following:

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') { 
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                sh 'qmake'


        sh 'make'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, i get this:

```
Obtained JenkinsFile from svn https://juasdt/svn/sas/branches/develop
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\sas
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
Updating https://juasdt/svn/sas/branches/develop at revision '2020-01-02T15:12:09.876 +0000' --quiet
Using sole credentials build/****** (SVN account) in realm ‘<https://juasdt:123> Server’
At revision 248

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Checkout)
[Pipeline] checkout
Updating https://juasdt/svn/sas/branches/develop at revision '2020-01-02T15:12:09.876 +0000' --quiet
Using sole credentials build/****** (SVN account) in realm ‘<https://juasdt:123> Server’
At revision 248

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
```

Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong or how i should go about this...

Comment: It appears that `qmake` is not in the user's path for whatever reason.

Comment: I've added it to the system path... was that not the right place? :(